# What is the id for the widgets section of the WordPress theme customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to add a control to the widgets section for the WordPress customizer, but I'm having a hard time finding the id for that section:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'sidebar_position', array(
    'label' => __( 'Sidebar Position' ),
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => array(
        // Options...
    ),
    'section' => '???', // <- Needed here.
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The widgets section ID is "widgets". Here's info for all the default Customizer sections/panels:

- Site Identity - title_tagline - 20
- Colors - colors - 40
- Header Image - header_image - 60
- Background Image - background_image - 80
- Navigation - nav - 100
- Widgets - widgets - 110
- Static Front Page - static_front_page - 120
- all others - default - 160